# Metodo Quicksort

Tags: java

Necesito saber como hacer que el metodo Quicksort me ordene de Mayor a menor, entiendo el ordenamiento original , de Menor a mayor pero no logro hacerlo en lo contrario,¿Debo relaizar los cambios dentro del ciclo while? o en el if dentro del ciclo while?

```
public void ordenarQ(int[] array) 
{
    array = quicksort1(array);
}

public int[] quicksort1(int numeros[]) 
{
    return quicksort2(numeros, 0, numeros.length - 1);
}

public int[] quicksort2(int numeros[], int izq, int der) {
    if (izq >= der) {
        return numeros;
    }
    int i = izq, d = der;
    if (izq != der) {
        int pivote;
        int aux;
        pivote = izq;
        while (izq != der) {
            while (numeros[der] >= numeros[pivote] && izq < der) {
                der--;
            }
            while (numeros[izq] < numeros[pivote] && izq < der) {
                izq++;
            }
            if (der != izq) {
                aux = numeros[der];
                numeros[der] = numeros[izq];
                numeros[izq] = aux;
            }
        }
        if (izq == der) {
            quicksort2(numeros, i, izq - 1);
            quicksort2(numeros, izq + 1, d);
        }
    } else {
        return numeros;
    }
    return numeros;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Una vez que termine el quickSort, invertí el arreglo.

```
//E es el tipo de dato que hay en el arreglo.
for(int i=0;i<arregloOrdenado.length/2;i++){
    E aux=arregloOrdenado[i];
    arregloOrdenado[i]=arregloOrdenado[arregloOrdenado.length-1-i];
    arregloOrdenado[arregloOrdenado.length-1-i]=aux;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tu versión de Java es 8, puedes utilizar el método reverse de `java.util.Collection`, pero antes debes convertir tu `array` `int` en un `array` `Integer`.

Para ello, utilizaremos [stream](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-in-java/):

Ejemplo:

```
//Cogemos el `array` y lo convertimos a `Integer`

int [] arr = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}; 
Integer[] list = Arrays.stream( arr ).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );
```

Ese `array` lo pasamos como argumento a una función, para darle la vuelta:

```
static void reverse(Integer a[]) 
{ 
    Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(a)); 
}
```

Solo quedaría mostrar por pantalla dicho `array`. Te dejo un ejemplo completo:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        int [] arr = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}; 
        Integer[] list = Arrays.stream( arr ).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );
        reverse(list); 
    } 

    static void reverse(Integer a[]) 
    { 
        Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(a)); 
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(a)); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Todas las respuestas te dan el array revertido, pero no es lo que se pide.

Cuando ordenas de menor a mayor lo que haces es buscar elementos a la izquierda del pivote que sean más grandes que este, luego elementos a la derecha que sean más pequeños, e intercambiar estos últimos, así de forma recursiva.

Para ordenar de mayor a menor, en vez de buscar elementos más grandes a izquierda y más pequeños a derecha, hazlo al revés: **Busca elementos más pequeños a la izquierda y más grandes a la derecha**

Eso se traduce en cambiar estas dos comparaciones:

```
// Comparaciones para ordenar de menor a mayor
numeros[der] >= numeros[pivote]
numeros[izq] < numeros[pivote]
```

Por estas otras:

```
// Comparaciones para ordenar de mayor a menor
numeros[der] <= numeros[pivote]
numeros[izq] > numeros[pivote]
```